# Golang high timeout for server

Tags: go

We have a simple http server that responds to POST requests. Normally it's running without any issues, but recently we decided to add in additional component for request analysis.

Currently it's as follows:

```
func handleRequest(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    if request.Method != "POST" {
        response.Write([]byte("Only POST"))
        return
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
    request.Body.Close()

    val := generateResponse(body)
    response.Write(val)
}
```

Normally the response time for this is around 40-50ms. Server usage at around 25%-30%.

With analysis tool added, the response time somehow increases even though it's on a separate routine.

```
func handleRequest(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    if request.Method != "POST" {
        response.Write([]byte("Only POST"))
        return
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
    request.Body.Close()

    val := generateResponse(body)
    response.Write(val)
    go doAnalysis(val)
}
```

Server usage is slightly higher at around 35%-40% due to additional processing. The response time is around 70-90ms now. Shouldn't spawning off a go-routine result in similar response time since response is written already?

Comment: What's the value of `GOMAXPROCS`?

Comment: It's set to NumCPU() - 1. So in our case it's going to 7 (8 core machine).

Comment: are you noticing the delay after the first few requests ? or right from the beginning when the server is started ? it would be useful to know the number of goroutines when each request is serviced in the handler using `runtime.NumGoroutine()`

Comment: What's your `go version`?

Comment: We are using GO 1.4 but have the same issue with another server that's on GO 1.5.

Comment: @algrebe It's from the start. The number of goroutine is fairly high (~2k) since we handle around 8-10k requests per second and we few routines running in background for updates.

Comment: what is your fd limit?

Comment: @jmaloney 200k for both

Comment: @Tesseract if the only thing that has changed is the addition of `go doAnalysis(val)` then could you try initializing around N `doAnalysisWorkers` that accept the val through a channel and do the analysis. Then the handler can write to the channel instead ( avoids the little goroutine creation overhead ). You can play around with the channel buffer size to prevent blocking (which will keep the handler routine active), but expect an increase in ram usage

Comment: @algrebe thanks for the suggestion. I was planing on doing that, but I was curious to know why the current implementation has increased response time even though it should spawn off an independent routine.

Comment: @Tesseract I was suggesting the implementation also as a test to figure out if the response time gets better as a result of lesser goroutines. While goroutines are very light weight, at scale, even lightweight things take their toll. Every request spawns a goroutine to handle it, and on top of that, another goroutine is spawned for each. This will have a crazy amount of goroutine. Given that true parallelism depends on the cores, there is bound to be some wait even though we think of it as an independent routine.